# Was "Aku Soku Zan" (悪即斬) a real Shinsengumi motto?

Tags: japan, samurai, meiji-restoration

In the manga series *Rurouni Kenshin*, the character of Hajime Saito, who is based on the real historical figure, has a saying or motto, "Aku Soku Zan" (悪即斬), which is translated as "Slay evil immediately".

I found a few claims online that this was a real motto of the [Shinsengumi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinsengumi) the group that both historical [Saito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sait%C5%8D_Hajime) and fictional Saito are part of, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sait%C5%8D_Hajime#Sait.C5.8D_in_fiction) says it was probably not:

> The "Aku Soku Zan" motto he lives by (悪即斬, most literally, "Kill those who are evil immediately,", translated as "Slay Evil Immediately" in the English dub and as "Swift Death to Evil" in the VIZ manga) is most likely fictitious, though it does encompass a common sentiment of the Shinsengumi during the [Bakumatsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakumatsu).

Is there any evidence that this phrase:

- Was a real Shinsengumi motto?
- Was a real motto of any contemporary group?
- Was a fictitious creation from literature or folk history that predated the manga series *Rurouni Kenshin*?

For the purposes of this question, if a reasonable search effort through reliable sources doesn't turn up evidence for any of the three things I asked about, it's fair to say that such evidence doesn't exist and I will upvote and possibly accept a well-formulated answer that argues along those lines. "Reasonable" search effort, "reliable" sources, and "well-formulated" answer are things I'll decide once I see them.

Comment: Hard to prove a negative

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps most telling is that the phrase is bad Classical Chinese. If I were to put it in English as "Evil, namely slay," that is not perfectly correct but would give a sense of the mangled grammar. The *Ruroni Kenshin* catchphrase is an uneducated riff on Chinese philosophical statements like 心即理 which are quite subtle in meaning and misunderstood by many modern Japanese people.

There are no Google Books results for 悪即斬 (that is,  "Aku Soku Zan") in the 20th century. Google Books has limited coverage of Japan before 1990 but at least something ought to come up. There are also [multiple](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1096780035) Japanese Yahoo Answers [posts](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10111026915) saying that the author of Ruroni Kenshin made this up.

There are not many historical sources for Hajime Saito, as it is said he was a man of few words.

Comment: Make sense but you miss quote the series. Aku soku zan was not the name of any attack. I'm assuming you mean the gatotsu or the amakakeru ryu no hirameki. I haven't found any demonstration for the later myself. It doesn't even make sense unless taken out of context perhaps because of a loss in translation referring to kenshins final attack. The shinsengumi from my limited study that is were basically guerilla warfare specialist (only interrested in holding Kyoto mind you), and in a extremely-broad unconventional sense in that many of them were limited skill wise but maste

Comment: you have confused this with the other answer, I did not write the other answer

Answer (score -2):

Both sides of the Meiji Revolution in 1868 Japan  (the Shogun and the Imperial Court) used "aku soku san" as a motto and a way of life, it was a radical sense of justice that they held and was believed to be the only way by samurai of that time. the anime about Kenshin Himura is based in a lot of fact and even most of the attacks (the ones the aren't humanly impossible, of course) are real including the aku soku zan. But it wasn't exclusive to the Shinsengumi

Comment: This answer could be improved immensely by giving some sources or references. As it stands, it is "you'll have to take my word for it".